# mongoose UnCaught TypeError: foundProduct.greet is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So the title says it all. Seems like for some reason I can't access the greet function, and I really don't understand why. I'm following a teacher froma  course and everything seems to be working fine on is side
this is the .js :

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shopApp")

    .then(() => {  //check if you succesfully connect to mongodb
        console.log("Connection Open !")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Oh No Error")
        console.log(err)
    })

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 20
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: [0, "Price must be positive !"]
    },
    onSale: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    categories: [String],
    qty: {
        online: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        inStore: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    },
    size: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["S", "M", "L"]//these are the only string that'll be accepted 
    }
})


const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema)

productSchema.methods.greet = function () {
    console.log("hello ! ")
    console.log(`- from ${this.name}`)
}


const findProduct = async () => {
    const foundProduct = await Product.findOne({ name: "Tire pump" });
    foundProduct.greet();
}
findProduct()
```

I know the problem is from const Product and below but cant find anything wrong

and here is the reponse a get when I .load product.js with node :

Uncaught TypeError: foundProduct.greet is not a function

Comment: Try to `console.log()` or debug your `foundProduct` constant, it is possible you are not connecting correctly to DB, or perhaps `Product.findOne` is not finding any object so it is possibly returning a void array/object.

Comment: You need to create model after adding methods & middleware that means `const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema)` should be after adding methods

Comment: @ArifKhan make it a response :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the instance method above

**const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema)**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).